# Hibernate Criteria Query Join with Null Value

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, criteria-api

I have a table called roles. Each role may belong to an organization. Roles that do not belong to an organization have a value of null. I want to find all the roles for a specific organization or where the organization is null within the table.

```
Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Role.class)
.add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.eq("organization",organization.getId()), 
        Restrictions.isNull("organization")));
```

The Mapping file has:

```
<many-to-one class="com.myname.models.Organization" name="organization">
<column name="organization_id" precision="22" scale="0" />
</many-to-one>
```

When the query runs, I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter com.myname.models.Organization.id
```

I have found that if I modify the criteria to just query for nulls on organization everything works, however once I query for a value, I get the error.

How to I modify the query or mapping file to meet my goals?

Comment: does `com.myname.models.Organiation.getId()` exist, and are you throwing an exception in it?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether you're still looking for the answer, but as I've encountered this thread during my search for a solution of the same problem, I though it might be helpful for future reference.

You'll need to construct your criteria as follows:

```
final Criterion lhs = Restrictions.eq("organization",organization.getId());
final Criterion rhs = Restrictions.isNull("organization");
Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Role.class).add(Restrictions.or(lhs, rhs));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter com.myname.models.Organiation.id
```

This seems to suggest that you are using "Organiation" somewhere whhere presumably this should be "Organization".

Comment: Nope, had to retype the code, so the error was in the translation between computers.